Using <div> as <button>, how to add `:active` pseudo style to it when pressing the space bar key?
Create a button with <div> tag, and also add styles behind the CSS code:
<div role="button" tabindex="0">foo</div>

When user press it with mouse, the div display the :active style. But when user use tab key to focus it, then press Space key, then the div won't display the :active style.
I can manual implement the onKeyDown logic code behind, but I cannot implement :active pseudo class, even with JavaScript.
Is there any way to implement the :active pseudo class?

Why I do not use button directly?
For some reasons, I have to nest a <button> in another <button>. In other words, the outer <button> is not a button, it just a container that happens to be clickable and can also trigger an onClick event by pressing the space bar key.
In addition, if I nest a button inside another button, when I focus on the inner button and press the space bar, the style of the outer button will become abnormal, that is, it will still keep the :active style after releasing the space bar, although the JavaScript logic behind are correctly.
Try to run the code below, and focus on the inner button, then press the space key, you will see the outer button will keep :active even if release the space key.


const outer = document.createElement("button");
outer.innerText = "Outer";
const inner = document.createElement("button");
inner.innerText = "Inner";
outer.append(inner);
document.body.append(outer);
button:active {
  color: red;
}




P.S. Use case
In WinUI 3 of Windows 11, there is a new control named "Expander". You can click the expander to expand or collapse children, and there are additional actions beside the chevron icon like toggle switches, combo boxes, buttons. The following picture shows the relevant use case of PowerToys.

In addition to being clicked with the mouse, they can also be pressed using the space bar. When tab focus on the expander, space to expand or collapse it; when focus on the buttons inside, space to click them.
Now I want to use the HTML to implement it. The problem is,
if I create the part of the expander where click to toggle expand by <div>, when the tab focus on it, press space won't show :active pseudo class;
if I create it by <button>, when the tab focus on the buttons inside, press space and then release, the expander outside will keep on :active style and won't automatically release.
In addition, since the latter has a button nested within a button, it is not a valid HTML and cannot be used in SSR (Server Side Rendering). Although you can hack it in the following way, it is not recommended and still doesn't solve the above problem.
<button>
    <object>
        <button></button>
    </object>
</button>

If make the inner button as position: absolute, and overlay it on the expander, this will indeed fix it. But you'll have to consider more layout issues. For example. To display the chevron icon, what is the margin-right for the inner buttons? Since the buttons' width changes by their text length, how can we ensure that the expander title and caption on the left side of the buttons are not obscured by the buttons if the title or caption are too long? If we do not use absolute positioning and place the buttons directly inside the expander, we do not have to consider these problems at all.

As you seem to know you can't nest a button in a button so I'm guessing you can't also fake a button around another button. The use case for this seems vague, clarity is needed

It looks more like you should change the outer button to a div as it doesnt behave more like a button. For me, a button should only contain an icon or text, not more childs.

Can you clarify, what these buttons are supposed to contain, or "say", in the real use case? It's probably not going to be "outer" and "inner", but right now we don't know whether it will be fixed, static texts, or something dynamic. If they are static - then you are probably way better off, if you did not try to nest elements here and then jump through hoops to re-implement button functionality on a non-button element - but rather positioned one actual button, over another one.

@Paulie_D The use case added.

@CBroe The use case added.

@Frankusky However actually I used to try to use outer button as a div, and manually bind enter keyDown and space keyUp to click event to behave like a real button. But I can't manually implement space keyDown to :active pseudo class style.

I solved the issue with the below approach. Just extended the css with :focus pseudo class.
button:focus:active {
    color: red;
}

Here's a full example. If you use the tab key to navigate on the inner button then press space it will work as you imagined but if you use the mouse to click on the inner button then there is another issue.


const outer = document.createElement("button");
outer.innerText = "Outer";
const inner = document.createElement("button");
inner.innerText = "Inner";
outer.append(inner);
document.body.append(outer);
  button:focus:active {
      color: red;
  }




When you focus and click (space) on Inner, then move focus back to Outer (shift + tab) - Outer will still be red!

That's true, I didn't know that I can reverse tabing
